# Get my data present in a Bus

Tags: vue.js

Hi everyone i work on a vue project but i have a problem i can't resolve.

The problem:

I transfering data between component with a bus i define in my main.js and i try to catch them in the destination component.

The destination component look like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="container is-fluid">
        <section class="hero is-dark">
            <div class="hero-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        {{itemTitle}}
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import { bus } from '../main'

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
            itemSummery: [],
            itemTitle: 'o',
            item: null
            }
        },
        created () {
            bus.$on('PostInfo', data => {
                this.itemTitle = data.title
                console.log(data)
            })
        },
        methods: {
            changeValue: function (data) {
                this.itemTitle = data.title
                console.log(this.itemTitle)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I can show data in console but when i assign them to `itemTitle` in created method my data doesn't change at all and `itemTitle` show 'o' on my page. Anyone can help me to avoid this problem and assign data do item ?

Thanks and sorry for my english ^^

Comment: I think you should move your data update logic in the mounted hook, not in the created.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code in this:

```
created() {
    var instance = this;
    this.$bus.$on('PostInfo', function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        instance.item = res;
        instance.itemTitle = res.title;
    });
}
```

The problem should be that inside your function the `this` is not the instance of your component.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finally found the solution.
I forget the bus element to pass data and i start to use vuex store like this:

```
Vue.use(Vuex)
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    data: null
  }
})
```

And in the file i want to send data i do that:

```
 goRetro: function (item) {
      this.$store.replaceState(item)
 }
```

And finally to capture data in the target component i do that:

```
 created () {
    var dataValue = this.$store.state
    this.itemTitle = dataValue.title
 }
```

[Finally have my title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG2YF.png)

I hope it can help people